# Form validation (react-admin library)

Tags: react-admin

Please tell me if there is a way to use the API of this library to show errors for the form that come from the backend part. Something like in the example below:

```
[
  { field: 'name', message: 'Field "name" must be of the string type' },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Check out https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#changing-the-success-or-failure-notification-message

Comment: that's not what I'm asking in the question. @DoctorAgon

Comment: Actually if you send the JSON from the Backend and parse it in the onFailure method after which update the form's state it should do exactly what you require. Could you clarify which part is not satisfied?